# Retrieve data from one table and order by related table column using Laravel eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1

I have two models Category and Transaction the table structures are like this

```
Categories:
id,category_name,..
```

and

```
Transactions:
id,category_id,amount..
```

The relation is

## Category hasMany transactions

```
public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

## Transactions blongsTo Category

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

I want to retrieve all data of **transaction** table which are sorted by **category** name.

Most importantly I want to get it using the eloquent method.
I have tried eager load which I think doesn't work on the belongsTo relationship.

Here is the code I have used for the eager load.

```
$transactions = Transaction::with(['category' => function ($query) {
                $query->orderBy('category_name', 'asc');
            }])->paginate(10);
```

So far I can achieve this by writing a query like below, but I'd like to use the eloquent method.

```
$transactions = Transaction::select(DB::raw('transactions.*'))
                ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(select id,category_name from categories) as categories'), 'categories.id', '=', 'transactions.category_id')
                ->orderBy('category_name', 'asc')
                ->paginate(10);
```

It'd be nice if someone can help me with this. Thank You.
Note: I am using Laravel 5.1

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution orther that the join method? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`$transactions = Transaction::with('categories')->group_by('category.name')->get();`

Comment: Sorry! this code is not working. I have tried similar code but it's not working. The error it throws it "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()". Seems with is not working with collections. 
I have tried to directly use "$transactions = Transaction::with('categories')->group_by('category.name')->get();" but it throws error Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::group_by().

Comment: Your updated answer gives this error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::group_by()" . I already tried this before posting the question. Do you have any suggestion @Dyan

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the method name that defines the relationship, in your case this is category.

`$transactions = Transaction::all()->with('category')->group_by('category.name')->get();`

Comment: The same answer has already given and that is not working please see @Dylan Pierce's answer and read the comments to see what I have got by using the code. Thank you

Comment: @Jnana actually it is slightly different as I am referencing the method name. Notice I have suggested using `->with('category')` as this is the actual name of your method that defines the relationship rather than `->with('categories')`. Referencing the method correctly should solve those issues you are getting as it will call a defined method.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to help me. I understand what you have tried to do. But sadly that doesn't work. From the answer of Dylan, I also have used category as there is no method like categories. Do you have any more idea ?

Comment: What error message do you get when you use category? The error below in the other answer refers to using categories

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with()

Comment: Updated my answer, removing the `all()` will make sure you're chaining Builders, instead of getting a Collection with the first method.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cs = Course::where(['courses.active' => 1])
->whereHas('course_dates', function ($join) use ($now) {
    $join->where('course_dates.start_date_time', '>', $now);
    $join->orderBy('course_dates.start_date_time', 'asc');
})
->whereHas('category', function ($join) use ($cat_slug) {
    $join->where('categories.url_slug', '=', $cat_slug);
})
->whereHas('language', function ($join) use ($cat_slug) {
    $join->where('languages.string_id', '=', strtoupper(App::getLocale()));
})
->with(['course_dates' => function($q){
    $q->orderBy('course_dates.start_date_time', 'desc');
}])
->join('course_dates' ,'course_dates.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
->orderby('course_dates.start_date_time')
->limit(7)
->get();
```

To return Eloquent models ordered by related model (`hasMany`) column, I had to join the tables and then `orderBy`, still get the models, but correctly ordered by course_date.start_date_time.

Laravel 5.7, I don't think there is a cleaner solution (at least after few hours of tinkering and searching the web).